# I cant figure out why divs can't be on one row when nothing is set do display:block

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to recreate some features of youtube. But I have been stuck on this problem for a while now and I can't figure out why the: "MainDiv"divs can't be on one row when nothing is set do display:block and when I inspect my code nothing is blocking the second div from being on the same line as MainDiv1.

I have been trying to put it as "display: grid, grid-template-columns: 300px 1fr;" But it just messes up the code.

```css
p {
  margin: 0px;
}

.Thumb1 {
  width: 300px;
}

.ChP1 {
  width: 40px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.DivChP1 {
  display: inline-block;
}

.DivText1 {
  display: inline-block;
}

.Text1 {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 250px;
  font-size: 13px;
  margin: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

.DivSubMain {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50px 1fr;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.Text2 {
  color: rgb(100, 100, 100);
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  display: inline;
}

.Text3 {
  color: rgb(100, 100, 100);
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin-top: 3px;
}

.MainDiv {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="MainDiv">
  <div>
    <img src="Thumbnails/Thumbnail1.webp" class="Thumb1">
  </div>
  <div class="DivSubMain">
    <div class="DivChP1">
      <img src="Thumbnails/channels4_profile.jpg" class="ChP1">
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="DivText1">
        <p class="Text1">Talking Tech and AI with Google CEO Sundar Pichai!</p>
      </div>

      <div class="DivText2">
        <p class="Text2">Marquez Brownlee</p>
      </div>

      <div class="DivText3">
        <p class="Text3">3.4M views &#183; 6 months ago</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="MainDiv">
    <div>
      <img src="Thumbnails/Thumbnail1.webp" class="Thumb1">
    </div>
    <div class="DivSubMain">
      <div class="DivChP1">
        <img src="Thumbnails/channels4_profile.jpg" class="ChP1">
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="DivText1">
          <p class="Text1">Talking Tech and AI with Google CEO Sundar Pichai!</p>
        </div>
        <div class="DivText2">
          <p class="Text2">Marquez Brownlee</p>
        </div>
        <div class="DivText3">
          <p class="Text3">3.4M views &#183; 6 months ago</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What output you want to achieve here? Do you want this two ```DivSubMain``` beside each other?

Comment: Yes, thank you , so the 2 menus are lined up horizontaly.

Comment: I will post an answer. I will glad if it will help you. If not, please inform me so I will delete the answer since posting code here in comment will not help you, I think.

Answer (score 0):

There're some *div's* that are unnecessary and I removed it.
You can use `display:inline-block` in parent div so it make it child beside each other.

```css
.MainDiv > div, .DivChP1, .DivText1, .ChP1 { /* I ADD THIS*/
    display: inline-block;
}
p {
    margin: 0px;
}
.Thumb1 {
    width: 300px;
}
.ChP1 {
    width: 40px;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
.Text1 {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin: 0px;
    width: 250px;
    font-size: 13px;
    margin: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="MainDiv">
    <div>
        <img src="Thumbnails/Thumbnail1.webp" class="Thumb1">
    </div>
    <div class="DivSubMain">
        <div class="DivChP1">
            <img src="Thumbnails/channels4_profile.jpg" class="ChP1">
        </div>
        <div class="DivText1">
            <p class="Text1">Talking Tech and AI with Google CEO Sundar Pichai!</p>
        </div>
        <div class="DivText2">
            <p class="Text2">Marquez Brownlee</p>
        </div>
        <div class="DivText3">
            <p class="Text3">3.4M views &#183; 6 months ago</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="Thumbnails/Thumbnail1.webp" class="Thumb1">
    </div>
    <div class="DivSubMain">
        <div class="DivChP1">
            <img src="Thumbnails/channels4_profile.jpg" class="ChP1">
        </div>
        <div class="DivText1">
            <p class="Text1">Talking Tech and AI with Google CEO Sundar Pichai!</p>
        </div>
        <div class="DivText2">
            <p class="Text2">Marquez Brownlee</p>
        </div>
        <div class="DivText3">
            <p class="Text3">3.4M views &#183; 6 months ago</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes it does, thanks for your help. I appreciate it a lot!